# How can I build up the understanding of a project?

Tags: undergraduate, project, resource-information, computational-thinking, active-learning

As a student my instructor gave me a scenario and a title and I have to work on that as a project. I searched a lot about these and watch videos , read blogs but didn't get a well defined answer. I have to understand the basic idea and working of that scenario and have to built up a project on that. But I am confused in getting the basic requirements and objectives of that scenario title based. Please if anyone can help me that how can I understand easily that title and get all points clearly? 
The given title is 'Online School Monitoring System'. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be improper to give you advice on the content of your project. Your professor assigned it so that you would learn something and you will learn more by doing that part yourself.

However, I think you are making a mistake by assuming that after the original instruction from your professor you can't go back for more advice. But if you just ask for help you may get less than you need. Again, that is because the professor wants you to do the work.

I suggest you do this. Before you actually start the project, write up a detailed proposal for what you think you should do based on the studying you have already done. "This is what I understand. This is what I propose to do." Use your own judgement about what are the best steps to take. You may be correct or not. Doing it will help you refine your ideas, of course.

Then, show that to your professor and ask for advice on it. If you make it clear that you have "done your homework" you are likely to get better advice. If you can do this in a face to face conversation you will also get to ask some questions about what you still see as gaps.

It isn't necessary to go from point A to point Z without any intermediate steps.  And it isn't precisely correct to ask others to fill in those steps.

Answer (score 3):

Each project manager will tell you that the success of your project refers to planning. This can take some effort at first, but in the long run having a clearly defined project plan will save you time, money, and a lot of headaches once you start the project. To start creating a project plan, focus on defining the project. Define goals and targets, define tasks, and be aware of legitimate killers and get feedback. A clearly defined project plan can help you guide you through the project, but this does not mean that you can completely neglect the project and expect it to be completed without reviewing, reviewing, and monitoring the project continuously. As a project management, you also have to be skillful in effective management of your time. If not, how do you expect the project to be completed on time?